# Search in a column for data that has does not have an address format

Tags: regex, oracle

During an import, I suspect some data has been corrupted. I want to search in an address column for data that does not have an address format. I created a query that searches for data like an address, but I soon realized that it would be better to search for data not like an address. This is the query I created:

```
SELECT STREET_ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(STREET_ADDRESS, '^m[0-9]' );
```

This query searches for rows that have address-like data but nothing comes up, and I know some rows have address like data. I think it would be better to show which rows in the table do not have address-like data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I even tried this an it came up with nothing;

Comment: I got it where now it will show some addresses and some that do not have an address format BUT I wanted it to show only what does not have an address format. this is the output I am getting:

Comment: SELECT STREET_ADDRESS FROM ADDRESS1 WHERE 
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(STREET_ADDRESS, '\d{1,3}.?\d{0,3}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,30}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}');          and Im getting output like this;

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

This query searches in a column (STREET_ADDRESS) where it is not in a physical address format

NOT REGEXP_LIKE (TRIM(STREET_ADDRESS), '^[0-9]'

Well, actually it searches to see if it starts out with a number  8.))